# Visual Studio に pydicom をインストールする方法

Tags: python

Visual StudioにPythonはインストールしています。

[pydicom](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/stable/index.html) をVisual Studioで利用できるようにしたいのですが、
イマイチインストールの仕方がよくわかりません。

教えて下さい。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 回答が投稿され解決した後、ご質問に「詳細を追加して欲しい」というマークがつきました。今回はもう解決してしまっているのでこれ以上質問者さんが何かしら書き足されるはしないかもしれませんが、次またご質問いただくときにどういう書き方だったらもっと良かったのかを知るための投稿をしてみましたので、ご興味あればご覧ください：[インストール方法を知りたい質問にあると嬉しい情報は何ですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3162/19110)

Answer (score 1):

ツール→Pythone(P)→Python環境(E)でPython環境が開きます。
概要の▼をクリックし、パッケージ(Pypl)を選択。
検索欄にpydicomと入力すると、pydicomのインストールが出てくると思います。
これでできないでしょうか？

Comment: できました。素晴らしい ありがとうございます。